# SQL query with group and limit

Tags: sql

Ive got table:

ID | cartID | type

- ID is PK.
- Many records can have the same cartID.
- cartID is only available for records with type 'A'.

In the UI the records with the same cartID and type 'A' are counted as one element.

I want to do paging so i want to fetch for example first 10 elements. At the moment I have really inefficient algorithm which fetch all records and then in code I'm grouping items with the same cartID and then im choosing top 10 elements

[image: Table]

Comment: You must have the order by in query for pagination along with limit. That is how you can make sure , you are not fetching the same data again and again!

Comment: Maybe i explained a bit wrong. This is how algorithm now works:
- i want to fetch 10 elements 
- im fetching whole table
- im summing records with the same cartID (if type 'A')
- then im taking 10 elements from prepared collection

The main problem here is fetching only required amount of data. I cant just fetch newest 10 records because there may be case that i fetched 10 records with the same cartID which on UI will be counted as one element.

Comment: `SELECT TOP 10 * FROM tableName WHERE type = 'A'` and if you want take the newest only You should add column with date when row was create.

Comment: @KlaudiuszDuda . . . You need to show the results that you want.  What happens if a given cart has more than 10 rows, for instance?  That exceeds your page size.  Also, you seem to want to return the data in some order, but you are not explicit about that.

Answer (score 0):

```
 with cte as
(select id,
 cartID,
 type,
 rank() over (partition by cartID order by cartID) as rank
where type = A)
select top 10 *
from cte 
order by rank asc
```